# Best implementation to send emails using crons

Tags: email, templates, cron, queue

I have a system which is already using cron to send emails. But i feel it is not a very good implementation, and i want to improve it. This is what i am doing right now:

Saving required 1 line text in database along with receiver's details, and couple of CTA's, and inside the cron i am adding that text in the main body, adding header & footer and sending it to user.

I am planning it to improve like this:

- Using blade templates.
- Creating different templates for different actions (eg registration, forgot password etc), right now there are no different templates.
- As soon as action is triggered, prepare the html email template which is ready to be sent to user, and save it in database.
- Use cron, pick the saved html template and send it to user.

I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. Is it fine to save whole html in database? or should i instead save variables in db as json and then use those variables to create the ready to be sent template in cron itself and then send it?
Or should i use some queuing methodology AWS provide to combine it with SES and submit emails to it without storing it in database.

Please suggest the best implementation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this in the following manner using AWS SES, Lambda & Dynamodb

- Configure SES to send email with your domain
- When you need to trigger an email, use a Table in DynamoDB to store the email data in JSON format.
- Configure Dynamodb streams to trigger a Lambda function upon new mail record creation, which will use SES SDK to send a mail.
- To construct the Email body in Lambda function, you can use a template mechanism of your choice (e.g for NodeJS you can use Underscore templating) and bind the JSON data before sending the email.

In this approach mails will be send asynchronously and also make sure you have extended the SES email quotas.

Comment: are there any cons (other than storage space issue) in storing the html body in the db?

Comment: No issue as far as I can see. The advantage in storing data only is that you can later change the template.